# change img src and unbind hover on menu selection jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, image, src

First question using stackoverflow! yay!

I have a [site](https://googledrive.com/host/0B7eDuLpoiC04ckRBVWlKSS1uMDg/index.html) I'm developing. It uses images as the menu options, and on hover, I've changed the img src in jquery

When you click the menu you want to go to, i want the image on hover to stay there. 
I did this:
`$("#one").click(function(){
$(this).attr('src', 'images/hover1.jpg');
$(this).unbind('mouseleave mousehover');`

So this is successful but the upon another menu click, i cant get the hover image to go away, and then it doesnt hover anymore (cause i unbinded it) - but binding it upon another menu click wasnt working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: WOow cool! thumbs up for your great work! ... hummm what was the question?

Comment: sorry, saved question before typing :P

Comment: yeah try harder to come up with a beginning of solution you didn't do much

Comment: I did try other stuff but nothing was working. Like i added the bind into the other menu clicks, to bind all the other menu's except the one being clicked. (so that the hover would work on those).

Comment: $("#two").click(function(){
        $("nav img").bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/hover2.jpg');});  - do you see my logic? - so i enable the hover to work on all the images, then disable the one being clicked

Comment: I also tried adding a class once clicked, using background-image as the image, cause 'content' wasn't working, but that didnt work either. Trust me, I wouldn't post a question unless I REALLY needed help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. I think its recommend to create a CSS solution here.

I checked out your javascript file and did some modifications in my browser. Finally I build you a possible working solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var hoverfuncIn = function(){ $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/(\D)(\.jpg)$/g,'$12$2')); };
   var hoverfuncOut = function(){ $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/2(\.jpg)$/g,'$1')); };
   var clickToggle = function(e){
    $('.selected').hover(hoverfuncIn,hoverfuncOut).removeClass('selected').mouseout();
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected').unbind('mouseleave mousehover');
}

   $('nav img').hover(hoverfuncIn,hoverfuncOut);

   $("#one").click(function(e){
      clickToggle(e);

...
```